# ActiveMQ Admin console Logout/Session timeout

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there a way to logout of **ActiveMQ** Admin console?

Also, once logged in to the admin console, is there a way to make the session timeout after some time of inactivity?

I tried to change the session timeout in the `web.xml` of the admin webapp but that didn't help.

Comment: I could not find something mentioned regarding timeout for the web app in the documentation. maybe it was done for purpose as it's an interface for messaging.

Comment: Isn't the admin web interface mainly for the admins? If yes, wouldn't you expect it to have some ways to secure the web console?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various combinations of closing the web admin page, removing cookies related to the activemq host, removing cookies containing "activemq" and restarting my web browser.

Of these, the only thing I've found which forces you to log in again is restarting the web broswer.

Answer (score 0):

A private / incognite window helped on my case.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't logout from ActiveMQ's web console.

ActiveMQ's authentication is done via HTTP Basic Authentication header and do not implement session handling on the server-side (that's why changing the `web.xml` didn't help). The session is ended simply by the browser by not sending the Authorization header anymore.